# create a nuget to share between linux and windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net form application using .net 4.6.1 running on windows
and a linux application using .netcore 1.1

I want to make a nuget that can be shared between both application.

I created a .net core library and it works pretty fine with my linux application
here is its project.jso

```
{
  "version": "0.1",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "StackExchange.Redis": "1.2.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "netcoreapp1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I can add my nuget package to the windows application and build it with no error, but when I want to run the application I'm getting all erros like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

i'm using .net 4.6.1 so I believe it's .net core that is nagging

i can check in [here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource) and confirm that it's a .net core library.

I also setup the .net library in the production server. but still i'm getting the same error.

I tried all possible combination and version that i thought it would be logical. and have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: You shouldn't import `netcoreapp1.0` in your framework declarations. Also you have twice the same entry. The import for `netstandard1.x` should be `portable-net451+win81` or something like that (`portable-net45+win8` or ``portable-net46+uap` or whatever you wish to have as minimum API - but remember, `portable-net45+win8` is the lowest PCL profile you can use with .NET Core)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you say you are using `net 4.6.1`. Because you are using `netstandard1.4` as framework, looking at your `project.json` file.

Try the following `project.json` file:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "debugType": "portable",
  "emitEntryPoint": true
},
"dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
  "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
  "StackExchange.Redis": "1.2.0"
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Make sure the production server has the runtime installed and `Microsoft.NETCore.App-1.1.0`